# How to make a text field unresizable/not stretch

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a super simple iPhone app in which the user enters a piece of information into a text field. It looks like this:

> Other Information: [TEXT FIELD]

The problem I am having is when the user enters a long sentence and clicks "done" on the keyboard, the text field stretches out so that it fits the entire long sentence, which ends up covering the "Other Information" label. I looked through attributes inspector but I couldn't find anything except for "Adjust to fit" under "min font size" which I thought might be it, but it did not work.

Here's a picture:

[image]

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you using auto layout? What constraints have you set up for the text field and the label?

Comment: @KenThomases yes I am. I only have Align X to Superview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're using auto layout, you need to set up constraints to prevent the problem. Typically, you would have constraints such as `@"|-[otherInformation]-[textField]-|"`. That makes sure that the text field is to the right of the label (assuming the text direction is left-to-right).

You would also want to set the compression resistance priority of the label to be relatively high and the compression resistance of the text field to be relatively low. So, if they can't both completely fit in the space between the two edges of the superview, the text field will be compressed before the label.

Similarly, you want the content hugging priority of the label to be relatively high and the content hugging priority of the text field to be relatively low. That's because, when the text field contents are short, you want the text field to stretch to fill the space between the label and the right edge of the superview. You don't want the label to stretch.